# gRPC + Bazel + Envoy Json Proxy - How to import google/api/annotations.proto

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, grpc, bazel

I have a very simple gRPC Service defined as:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package helloworld;
import "annotations.proto";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/api/v1/hello"
      body: "*"
    }
  }
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

The interesting aspect is that I'm using the Envoy gRPC <> JSON transcoding filter to "translate" between HTTP2/Protobuf <> HTTP1/JSON. See https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v1/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter for more details.

Further, I'm using Bazel to build the Java based gRPC Services. The Envoy transcoding filter requires some annotations:

```
option (google.api.http) = {
  post: "/api/v1/hello"
  body: "*"
}
```

I'm using the proto_library (https://github.com/cgrushko/proto_library) to generate the corresponding .java files from the .proto definitions, but I'm not able to add the

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
```

to the .proto files, as I have no idea how to import https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/annotations.proto to a bazel project.

Thank you.

Best Regards, 
jj

Comment: (1) Thanks for posting this. To improve the question, I think it's better to remove unrelated things like the mention of Envoy. (2) did you mean to import `google/api/annotations.proto` (and not `"annotations.proto"`) at the top of your file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The ugly, unmaintainable super-fast way: vendor the file

You can usually copy a `.proto` to your own project and build against it; as long as the upstream proto doesn't change "too much" it will continue working.

If, for example, `googleapi` surveys who's using their repo, they won't find your usage if you copied the file.

Once you have the file in your repo you can follow the example in https://github.com/cgrushko/proto_library/blob/04369f0d2ade8c8566727e0b6f3a53f1ba8925c0/src/BUILD.

## The maintainable way: external repository

An external repository (e.g. [`http_archive`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#http_archive)) allows you to depend on another Bazel project. With `http_archive`, it will be downloaded and built as part of your build.

With `http_archive`, the external project must already build with Bazel, which is not exactly the case for `googleapi`: it doesn't have a BUILD file for `google/api/annotations.proto`.

One option is to talk with them and see if they can add such a BUILD file (or send a PR yourself). The other option is to use [`new_http_archive`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_http_archive) and provide your own BUILD file as part of the definition.

Adding the following to your `WORKSPACE` file (at the root of your project) should work more or less:

```
new_http_archive(
  name = "googleapi",
  url = "https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/archive/common-protos-1_3_1.zip",
  strip_prefix = "googleapis-common-protos-1_3_1/",
  build_file_content = "proto_library(name = 'annotations_proto', srcs = ['google/api/annotations.proto'])"
)
```

Then, you'd be able to depend on it your code:

```
proto_library(
  name = "hellow_world_proto",
  ...
  deps = ["@googleapi//:annotations_proto"],
)
```

Comment: The latest googleapis code does have BUILD.bazel file. I tried using a git_repository to refer to it.
git_repository(
    name = "googleapis",
    remote = "https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.git",
    commit = "3aeb3a70f66457a9e6b07caff841719bb9873b57",
)
I tried to refer to annotations.proto as a depdendency
proto_library(
    name = "product_proto",
    srcs = ["product.proto"],
    deps = [
        "@googleapis//googleapis/google/api:annotations_proto"
    ], 
)

Comment: I get this error, no such package '@googleapis//googleapis/google/api': BUILD file not found in directory 'googleapis/google/api' of external repository @googleapis

Answer (score 1):

I followed the second proposal (The maintainable way: external repository) and ended up with:

WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
name = "com_google_protobuf",
sha256 = "cef7f1b5a7c5fba672bec2a319246e8feba471f04dcebfe362d55930ee7c1c30",
strip_prefix = "protobuf-3.5.0",
urls = ["https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.5.0.zip"],
)

new_http_archive(
name = "googleapi",
url = "https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/archive/common-protos 1_3_1.zip", 
strip_prefix = "googleapis-common-protos-1_3_1/",
build_file="BUILD.googleapi"
)
```

BUILD.googleapi

```
package(default_visibility=['//visibility:public'])

proto_library(
name = 'annotations_proto',
srcs = ['google/api/annotations.proto'],
deps = [
        ":http_proto",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:descriptor_proto"
    ],
)

proto_library(
name = 'http_proto',
srcs = ['google/api/http.proto'])
```

BUILD

And finally a reference to the annotation.proto from the BUILD file:

```
proto_library(
name = "GreeterServices_proto",
srcs = ["GreeterServices.proto"],
deps = [
    "@googleapi//:annotations_proto",
])
```

Regards, 
jj

Comment: I tried your solution in bazel(0.25.3), it occurs bellow error:


C:/users/cen/_bazel_cen/rmmz4bjv/external/googleapi/BUILD.bazel:7:10: Label '@googleapi//:google/api/annotations.proto' crosses boundary of subpackage '@googleapi//google/api' (perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@googleapi//google/api:annotations.proto'?)